# mesh shrink too much when i move a bone

Tags: rigging, surface-deform

hi I'm trying to rig my character but i am having this annoying issue when i rig the shoulders and arms! when i move the arm up the mesh shirnks way too much. i tried to wheight paint but if i add wheight the deltoid goes down, if i remove weight it just dont deform am i missing something? btw i am using old version of blender because my onboard video doesnt support open  gl

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: ...and also you should mention which blender version you are using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a simple weight painting error combined with a joint misplacement.

1. The top of the shoulder is not weighted with the arm, so it digs into it like a rigid shoulder plate armor piece. I suggest trying automatic weights. But first consider,
2. The joint for the shoulder appears to be too far out from the body, but it’s hard to tell without a screenshot showing the relaxed armature. I suggest editing the armature so that joint is closer to the body, probably coplanar with the side.